# How to select multiple columns including the foreign entity using JPA EntityManager

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

I am trying to select multiple columns from 2 tables with OneToOne relationship, where the users will send the columns they want to search and the sever returns the result list contains only those columns. I have two entities like these:

```
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "id" )
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Address address;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

```
public class Address  implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Column(name = "user_id" )
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String houseNr;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Networkdata networkdata;
    
    //Getters and Setters
```

With search functions using EntityManager with Tuple

```
public List<?> find(String[] neededFields){
   if(neededFields.length > 0){
      String queryStr = this.createQueryString(neededFields);

      TypedQuery<Tuple> query = em.createQuery(queryStr, Tuple.class);

      List<Map<String, Object>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        
      query.getResultList().forEach(tuple -> {
         Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
         List<TupleElement<?>> elements = tuple.getElements();
         for (TupleElement<?> element : elements ) {
            String alias = element.getAlias();
                    
            map.put(alias, tuple.get(alias));
         }
                
         resultList.add(map);
      });

      return resultList; 
   }
   else{
      return em.createQuery(this.FIND_ALL_STR, User.class).getResultList();
   }
}
```

When i search using `SELECT u FROM User u, Address a WHERE u.id = a.id`. It returns result like this:

```
[
   {
      "id": "5e4e3c95cd8b290008db6f3c",
      "name": "name",
      "address": {
         "id": "5e4e3c95cd8b290008db6f3c",
         "houseNr": "123ABC"
      }
   }
]
```

Another case is `SELECT u.address as address FROM User u, Address a WHERE u.id = a.id` which returns

```
[
   {
      "address": {
         "id": "5e4e3c95cd8b290008db6f3c",
         "houseNr": "123ABC"
      }
   }
]
```

But when i add a little spicy ingredient like for example, to select the id and the whole address entity like this `SELECT u.id as id, u.address as address FROM User u, Address a WHERE u.id = a.id` it returns

```
[
   {
      "id": "5e4e3c95cd8b290008db6f3c",
      "address": null
   }
]
```

Why the first two queries are perfectly fine but the last just returns a `null` address?
How can i solve this?

Other ideas are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you searching from two column, you can actually use INNER JOIN key words with FOREIGN KEY on the Adress. If you still want to trim down your search you can always use WHERE clause.
SELECT u.id as Id,    a.address as Adress from User u INNER JOIN Address a ON u.id=a.user.id .
to trim down your search you can add “WHERE u LIKE %?1% AND a LIKE % ?1% ORDER BY u.id “

Better still to save yourself from headache you can use RESPONSE CLASS to map out the column you want to search from something like SELECT new UserAddress(u.id, a.address) ......

I hope I’m able to help.

Comment: I have tried `INNER JOIN` as you suggested, but the result still remains the same. For the response classes, I can't use those because I don't know beforehand which field will be selected because the field will be selected dynamically by the user.

Comment: I think you can use response class to accept their request then make sense of it in your query. I think that is the best way. You can always Index the table you want people to search from since your tables are in the database. The best way is to include the column to search in your search param.